# android activity restarting itself

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a task app with Firebase. I've got a problem with removing (and undoing the remove operation).

I have the following activities:

- **`TaskList`** - Shows a list of the tasks
- **`TaskView`** - A detailed view of a task (launched from recyclerView in `TaskList`)
- **`CompletedTask`** - An activity that launches to play a neat anim when you complete a task (launched from `TaskView`)

When `CompletedTask` is launched from `TaskView`, I remove the value entry using `taskReference.removeValue()` then I pass all the required data for that task through the intent (`uid, title, dueDate` etc).. Once `CompletedTask` launches I create an undo button in case the user wants to undo.

So when inside the `CompletedTask` activity, the entry has been removed and we have all the data we need to put it back if the user requires.

**The Issue**

When I press the undo button, it's supposed to put the `TaskItem` back into the database and `startActivity` back to TaskList **but** all that happens is the `completedTask` activity gets restarted every time I press undo and the database entry gets put back and immediately removed again.

I've tried various debugs to try and find the problem area but I've come to a wall with it. I've posted the `CompletedTask` activity below as this is where the error is occuring (I think!)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

**ActivityCompletedTask:**

```
private String uid, title, subject, subjectColor;
private long dateDue;
private DatabaseReference mTaskRef;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private TaskItem taskItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_completed_task);

    //set status bar color
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#42a566"));

    //create task item and put it back in the db
    Intent data = getIntent();

    //get data passed from intent
    uid = data.getStringExtra("uid");
    title = data.getStringExtra("title");
    dateDue = data.getLongExtra("dateDue", 1);
    subject = data.getStringExtra("subject");
    subjectColor = data.getStringExtra("subjectColor");

    //create task item
    taskItem = new TaskItem(title, dateDue, subject, subjectColor);
    taskItem.setUid(uid);

    //firebase connection with task ID
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mTaskRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
            .child("tasks")
            .child(mUser.getUid())
            .child(taskItem.getUid());

    }

    //undo clicked
    public void undoComplete(View view){

        //push item back into db
        mTaskRef.setValue(taskItem);

        finishActivity();
    }

    //go back to task list
    private void finishActivity(){

        startActivity(new Intent(ActivityCompletedTask.this, ActivityTaskList.class));


    }
```

*Edit*

Adding code snippet for launching `CompletedTask` from `TaskView` in case there's something wrong there..

```
  public void CompleteTask(final View view) {

    mTaskRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                TaskItem taskItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(TaskItem.class);

                myUid = taskItem.getUid();
                myTitle = taskItem.getTitle();
                myDateDue = taskItem.getDuedate();
                mySubjectName = taskItem.getSubjectName();
                mySubjectColor = taskItem.getSubjectPrimaryColor();

                //remove value
                mTaskRef.removeValue();
                iCompletedAThing();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + 
databaseError.getCode());
        }
    });

}

private void iCompletedAThing(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityViewTask.this, 
ActivityCompletedTask.class);
    //put all myTask item data into intent
    intent.putExtra("uid", mTaskKey);
    intent.putExtra("title", myTitle);
    intent.putExtra("dateDue", myDateDue);
    intent.putExtra("subject", mySubjectName);
    intent.putExtra("subjectColor", mySubjectColor);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

Comment: What's the device?..What if If the local storage is full? ..Sometimes the local  db may over cook can cause restarting of the device.

Comment: The device I'm testing on is my Nexus 6. It's the activity that is restarting, not the device.

Comment: Oops my bad for stating that as device...

Comment: curious you seem to be calling a new instance of the TaskList class without finish() ing it or anything. Maybe try adding an Intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to finishActivity() intent, it may be something to do with the back stack?